# Code completion in CounterClockWise?

Tags: clojure, code-completion, ccw

I am a first-time user of CounterClockWise, the Eclipse plugin for Clojure, and it appears that code completion just won't work. I keep wondering whether the problem lies between my keyboard and my chair, but can't find a solution. I just installed CCW on Galileo build 20090920-1017 and MacOSX. Then I try to write some lines of clojure code, and no code completion widget comes up. I'm using the Java perspective. Am I missing something? I somehow hoped it would work out of the box, as I'm just starting with Clojure.

Many thanks in advance!

Costas

Answer (score 3):

I'm using CCW 0.0.62.STABLE01 and code completion works. Press control space to bring up a list of possible items and as you type, the list is filtered. Press return at any point to accept the first item in the list or use the up/down arrows to select another item. Press esc to dismiss the list.

Comment: In 0.10.2.STABLE001 it is still broken (sometimes just don't work without giving any info to me why). I can't figure out what causes this, and it is frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here (http://www.chaomancy.com/blog/clojure-in-eclipse-part-2-counterclockwise-maven.html):

"But most of Counterclockwise's features come to life once you start a REPL. For Counterclockwise is really built around the REPL; without one running, things such as code completion will not work."

Answer (score 0):

I dont see code completion in the ccw [list of completed features](http://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise/) though I dont know how well this feature list is kept up to date

edit: its now marked completed.

Comment: Well, they mention it as completed (it's in bold) and it also exists in the screenshots... Very confusing. I may contact the developers.